# Linux Mint 18 - connecting a bluetooth headset disables USB mouse

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth

I'm trying to get a bluetooth headset to work on my Mint 18 Cinnamon. I can connect to the headset in the normal mode, but most of the time when switching to A2DP mode for better quality, my USB mouse stops working. It is still powered on, and recognized in lsusb, but does not react to clicks or movement. I can use my wireless mouse as normal in this case.

Sometimes the connection works, and sometimes I get an error from pulseaudio "Failed to change profile to a2dp_sink". I don't know if this error is in any way related.

The problem did occur on a clean Live-USB version of LM18 as well, so I don't think it's due to any updates gone wrong. When I have the USB mouse unplugged, then connect to the headset and then reconnect the mouse, it works normally.

Any pointers on where to start debugging this? 
Dmesg doesn't show anything exiting, except for a few lines of

```
Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 6
```

EDIT: The mouse also freezes when sending files to mobile phone through BT. Seems like high activity causes the issue?

Comment: How is your wireless mouse connected?

Comment: It's through and USB dongle that also handles a wireless keyboard.

lsusb: Bus 003 Device 006: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is a bit of a lackluster. I updated my BIOS to the newest version and the mouse now works as it should.

Motherboard: Gigabyte Z87-D3H

Previous BIOS: F7

New working BIOS: F9